# Applying K means clustering to 3 dim data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

I am trying to apply k-means clustering in sklearn on a (52,168,2) dimensional dataset. As expected, it's giving dimension error for the estimator as 2D data is expected. What should be the way forward?

I have wind and load data in two separate files for a year with weekly data (one-hour resolution) in each row in both the files. The wind and load data are correlated (i.e., week 1 wind data corresponds to week 2). I am trying to apply K-means clustering to reduce operating periods from 52 weeks to an appropriate number of weeks(ideally 12 weeks). Hence, each data point, in this case, is a 168*2 np array with weekly wind and load data combined.

The dimension of data is coming out to be (52,168,2), since I have 52 weeks and each data point is 168*2. However, I can't apply this to sklearn k-means as it requires 2D data. I am wondering if i reshape data as data.reshape(52,168*2), will it preserve what I am aiming to do?

```py
Load_data = pd.read_csv('Scenario_Load_Data.csv', header = None) 
Load_data_final = Load_data.to_numpy() 
Wind_data = pd.read_csv('Scenario_Wind_Data.csv', header = None) 
Wind_data_final = Wind_data.to_numpy()

create_list = []

for i in range(len(Load_data_final)):
 intermediate_v = np.column_stack((Load_data_final[i,:],Wind_data_final[i,:]))
create_list.append(intermediate_v)
data = np.array(create_list)
```

ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.

Answer (score 0):

As you wanna group that by week, I believe that you can concatenate the wind and load data in the same array. I mean, 1 week will be a line and 168 + 168 will be the attributes. So, you're gonna have something like:

```
Week_1: at1, at2, at3, ..., at336    
Week_2: at1, at2, at3, ..., at336    
...    
Week_52: at1, at2, at3, ..., at336
```

SO, I think it's pretty much like you're intending to do with `reshape`